# Need to upload image to AWS S3 server using fastify-multer getting [Function: multerPreHandler] error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, fastify

1. Packages used

```
const fastify = require('fastify');
        const multer = require('fastify-multer');
        const server = fastify();
        server.register(multer.contentParser);
        var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
        var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

[inspired by Rohan Paul](https://medium.com/@paulrohan/file-upload-to-aws-s3-bucket-in-a-node-react-mongo-app-and-using-multer-72884322aada)
2. Function To upload file to AWS S3 bucket

```
   uploadInvoice = async (req, res) => {
             var files = upload.single("file");
             try {
             
             const s3FileURL = ' https://up.s3.amazonaws.com/';
         
             let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
                 secretAccessKey: "",
                 accessKeyId: "",
                 region: ""
             });
         
             const params = {
                 Bucket: '',
                 Body: files.buffer,
                 ContentType: files.mimetype,
                 ACL: "public-read",
                 key: files.originalname
             };
            
             s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, files) {
                 if (err) {
                     res.status(500).json({ error: true, Message: err });
                 } else {
                     res.send({ files });
                     var newFileUploaded = {
                         description: req.body.description,
                         fileLink: s3FileURL + files.originalname,
                         s3_key: params.Key
                     };
                     var document = new DOCUMENT(newFileUploaded);
                     document.save(function (error, newFile) {
                         if (error) {
                             throw error;
                         }
                     });
                 }
             });
         };
```

ERROR that I am getting is
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/upload/files", ok: false, …}
error: {statusCode: 500, error: "Internal Server Error", message: "params.Body is required"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/v1/upload/files: 500 Internal Server Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/upload/files"
**proto**: HttpResponseBase

Comment: update: Multer wasn't really working in this case I used fs and pump for file upload and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for fs and pump and NOT multer if you are using fastify because as of now fastify-multer didn't exactly work with AWS S3 uploads

Comment: how to do that exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

In your params, the "key" is in lowercase whereas while uploading your are using params.Key which should be params.key

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try on using `multer-s3`. It should also work with `fastify-multer`.

Check the link to multer-s3 for further reference and examples at:

https://github.com/anacronw/multer-s3